# Instantiating an Interface Listener in Kotlin

Tags: android, interface, kotlin

I cannot, for the life of me, instantiate an interface outside of a fragment in Kotlin or Kotlin for Android. It was standard procedure in Java to say something like:

```
MyInterface mInterfaceListener = new MyInterface(this);
mInterfaceListener.invokeSomeGenericMethod();
```

Note that mInterfaceListener is referring to an Interface, not an onCLickListener or anything like that

**How are interfaces instantiated in Kotlin? How do I make a "listener" and trigger an interface's functions?**

Below are some attempts in a very simple app I am doing for learning purposes. Notice the variable *mPresenterListener* which is an Interface

```
    class QuoteActivity : QuoteContract.ViewOps, AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var vText: TextView
    private lateinit var vFab: FloatingActionButton
    private lateinit var mPresenterListener: QuoteContract.PresenterOperations

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mPresenterListener = this.mPresenterListener
        vText=findViewById(R.id.main_quote)
        vFab=findViewById(R.id.main_fab)
        vFab.setOnClickListener{
            mPresenterListener.onQuoteRequested()
        }
    }

    override fun displayQuote(quote: String) {
        vText.text = quote
    }

}
```

And my presenter:

```
    class QuotePresenter(private val viewListener: QuoteContract.ViewOps): QuoteContract.PresenterOperations {

    private lateinit var modelListener: QuoteContract.ModelOperations

    init {
        modelListener = this.modelListener
    }


    override fun onQuoteRequested() {
        modelListener.generateQuote()
    }

    override fun onQuoteGenerated(quote: String) {
        viewListener.displayQuote(quote)
    }


}
```

The interface:

```
interface QuoteContract {



//Methods available to Presenter (Presenter -> View)
interface ViewOps{
    fun displayQuote(quote: String)
}


//Ops offered from presenter to view (Presenter->View)

interface PresenterOperations {
    //Presenter->View
    fun onQuoteRequested()
    //Presenter->Model
    fun onQuoteGenerated(quote: String)
}

//Ops offered from Model to Presenter (Model -> Presenter)
interface ModelOperations {
    fun generateQuote()
}
```

}

Comment: Is this specific to interfaces or listeners, or are you asking how to create objects in general?

Comment: You're already implementing an interface inside of `setOnClickListener` since that requires a `new View.OnClickListener`

Comment: `mPresenterListener = this.mPresenterListener`  and `modelListener = this.modelListener`. Why are use assign the variable to itself?

Comment: This is in regards to interfaces themselves. I have updated the question to include the code for the interface to make it more clear. I am trying to make it so any active classes/views that implement the interface will execute the interface's methods. As for assigning it to itself, yeah, that was me throwing mud at the wall to see what sticks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do watchers/listeners like this:

```
val textView: TextView = this.findViewById(R.id.amountEdit)
val watcher = object : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
        val inputAmount = textView.text.toString
        val amount = if (!inputAmount.isEmpty()) inputAmount.toDouble() else 0.0
        conversionViewModel?.convert(amount)
        }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        println("before text changed called..")
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        println("text changed..")
    }
}
```

and then:

```
textView.addTextChangedListener(watcher)
```

Notice the object in declaring the watcher. Can do the same with a listener.

Comment: Ok, so just to wrap my head around your method: Textwatcher is an interface and you are assigning it to a singleton? How would this work in a typical MVP scenario? Thank you for your answer

Comment: Why is it a singleton? it's an instance. This is one of the many great things about Kotlin: you can make instances out of interfaces, as objects.

Comment: The mini-course I had taken defined the Singleton in Kotlin as an Object which can only have one instance of itself. I see Singleton sometimes in dependency injection, so I am not sure if there is some vocabulary overlap. Anyway, thank you for following up with my "answer". Yours is the answer, I just got lost with all the TextView shinnanigans and I wasn't sure if TextWatcher was an interface or some Android library class. Regardless, you helped me out and answered the question: assign it to an object. Much much easier than my solution. Thank you

Comment: Sure, glad it helped @JoshRibeiro, good on you for wanting to learn the right way to do things. This question caught my eye because when I was learning the new Android Blueprints I had the exact question of how best to adapt the Java approach.

Answer (score 5):

Also we can use listener without some interface and with default value like:

```
val someButtonListener: (isChecked: Boolean) -> Unit = {_ -> }
val someButtonListener: (v: View) -> Unit = {_ -> }
```

Comment: Simple and perfect